# Ajax update keeps setting tab body to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, setinterval

I'm using `setInterval()` to update tab content using `ajax`, however I want it to keep the same tab open after the update is complete. The current code keeps the `li` formatting correct i.e the same link is displayed as active and the title is the same, however the body reverts to the original. The code in the first box only executes when the first update is executed in order to format the first `li` as active.  When a different tab is clicked, it hides the active tab and removes `#theOpen` and then sets those properties to the new tab.

```
 if (!isUpdate) {
            //When page loads...
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
            $("ul.tabs li:first").attr("id", "theOpen");
            $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
            var titName = $("ul.tabs li:first").find("a").attr("href") + 'IDer';
            var theName = $(titName).html();
            $('#stationTitler').text($(titName).html());
        }
        else {
            var activeTab = $("#theOpen").find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content

        }
```

Comment: paste ur code in jsfiddle

Comment: I haven't used it before, but I only have IE8 at work and it won't load.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the description is a little bit vague, however for anyone who is interested, I have fixed this. At the end of the function called in set interval I simply replace

```
 else {
            var activeTab = $("#theOpen").find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content

        }
```

with

```
else {
    $("#theOpen").trigger("click");
}
```

Before I was trying to change the property of the tab bodies, however I have already written jQuery code for the tabs and this simply follows the same routine of opening the particular tab.

I was trying to pass the url of the tab to the `.fadeIn()` function, however the `.li` class already has an onclick listener, so I can simply trigger a click for the same effect, as shown above.